# Traefik/Docker/Wildfly - Cannot access Wildfly management console

Tags: docker, wildfly, traefik

I'm running Traefik in a Docker container, with Wildfly in other container.

I have the following labels in Wildfly's docker-compose.yml:

```
  - "traefik.web.port=8080"
  - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:temporary_wildfly_hostname"
  - "traefik.admin.port=9990"
  - "traefik.admin.frontend.rule=Host:temporary_wildfly_hostname;PathStrip:/console/"
```

I can access the main Wildfly, which is in port 8080. I've tried many ways to access the service in port 9990, but the only one which really works is when I use a different Host, which isn't what I want.

I've tried:

- Added "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true" (even with .admin before .frontend)
- Switching PathStrip with PathPrefixStrip, Path PathStripRegex or even PathPrefixStripRegex

Wildfly's management console uses port 9990, redirects from :8080/console and also uses :9990/console/*, so /console by itself is redundant and it shows "too many redirects" errors.

I really think this /console loop error is some kind of an issue. I've been searching online for alternative configurations for other reverse proxies, to see if I'm missing something, but all relate to the headers, which I've already tried.

Any hint on how can I solve this, keeping the same URL, but still redirecting to a different port than the main service?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Best regards,

Luis Nabais

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [priority](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/basics/#priorities) on each [segment](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels).

```
traefik.<segment_name>.frontend.priority=10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However the solution was different. I posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer.

The issue was related to the backend wildfly creates. It uses another URL, which is /management. So I solved it using the following traefik labels:

```
  - "traefik.web.port=8080"
  - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:temporary_wildfly_hostname"
  - "traefik.admin.port=9990"
  - "traefik.admin.frontend.rule=Host:temporary_wildfly_hostname;PathPrefix:/console,/management"
```